# Re-write oracle query to avoid multiple table scan

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope everyone is fine and learning more. I need some advice on select statement and on its fine tuning. I am using Oracle 11gR2.  Please find below table and data scripts.

```
create table employee (emp_id number, emp_name varchar2(50), manager_id number);
create table department (dept_id number, dept_name varchar2(50), emp_name varchar2(50), manager_level varchar2(20));
create table manager_lookup (manager_level_id number, manager_level varchar2(20));
insert into employee values (1, 'EmpA',3);
insert into employee values (2, 'EmpB',1);
insert into employee values (3, 'EmpC',1);
insert into employee values (4, 'EmpD',2);
insert into employee values (5, 'EmpE',1);
insert into employee values (6, 'EmpF',3);
insert into department values (1, 'DeptA','EmpD','Level3');
insert into department values (2, 'DeptB','EmpC','Level2');
insert into department values (3, 'DeptC','EmpA','Level1');
insert into department values (4, 'DeptD','EmpF','Level1');
insert into department values (5, 'DeptD','EmpA','Level3');
insert into department values (6, 'DeptA',NULL,'Level3');
insert into manager_lookup values (1, 'Level1');
insert into manager_lookup values (2, 'Level2');
insert into manager_lookup values (3, 'Level3');
commit;
```

Below query is returning me dept_id by passing some emp_name. I need those dept_id where manager_level is same as emp_name passed but don't need to have that same emp_name in result data set.

```
SELECT b.dept_id
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT manager_level
          FROM department dpt
         WHERE emp_name = 'EmpA'
         and emp_name is not null) a,
       department b
 WHERE     a.manager_level = b.manager_level
       AND NVL (b.emp_name, 'ABC') <> 'EmpA';
```

Above query is returning me data set as below:

```
dept_id
--------
1
4
6
```

I want same result set but need to rewrite above query in a way to avoid department table scan two times. This is just sample query but in real time scanning big table two times is giving performance issues. I want to re-write this query in a way to perform better and avoid same table scan two times.

Can you please help on providing your wonderful suggestions or solutions? I will really appreciate all responses.

Thank you for going over the question.

Comment: First suggestion is that the `DISTINCT` in your subquery does nothing at all.

Comment: Also, You don't need to check `IS NOT NULL` in addition to `=`.  `=` never matches against `NULL`.

Comment: And what are you trying to do with that `NVL`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your query to be more efficient, then use indexes:

```
create index idx_department_name_level on department(emp_name, manager_level)
```

and

```
create index idx_department_name_level on department(manager_level, emp_name, dept_id)
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for the suggestion. I will try to implement this and check on performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

also, you have a redundant null check which may be avoiding indexes...

```
SELECT b.dept_id
  FROM (SELECT manager_level
          FROM department dpt
         WHERE emp_name = 'EmpA') a,
       department b
 WHERE     a.manager_level = b.manager_level
       AND NVL (b.emp_name, 'ABC') <> 'EmpA';
```

post your explain plan for more help

Comment: Hi Randy, Thank you for your reply. Null check is needed because I need to consider null values for emp_name too. This is just a sample scenario and explain plan will not help in this case, as I dint create indexes on these sample tables. I am looking for query rewrite to avoid table scan two times.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
(
    SELECT d.*,
        SUM(CASE WHEN emp_name = 'EmpA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY manager_level) AS hits
    FROM department d
) a
WHERE hits > 0
  AND NVL(emp_name, 'Dummy') <> 'EmpA'
ORDER BY dept_id
;
```

The query does the following:

1. Calculate how many times `EmpA` appears in a given `manager_level`
2. Keep all records with a `manager_level` that has at least one occurrence of `EmpA` in it
3. Excluding the `EmpA` records themselves

SQL Fiddle of the query in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9e03/7
You can verify that the execution plan contains only one full table scan.

Comment: Thank you Llama. This query is great help. I will check for performance on this.